# Mixin design to extend template parameter struct for various applications

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, decorator, mixins

I have a templated class that accepts structs as parameters (there is a reason for this that I won't get into here, but the design requires it). I am trying to generate a mixin design pattern (static decorator) that can be used with this class for maximum flexibility and extensibility, but I appear to be stuck in template hell with obscure compiler messages and cannot determine the issue.

I have a class like this:

```
// User extensible struct
struct X {
    ...
};

struct Y {
    ....
};

template <class T = X, class U = Y>
class Derived : public Base<T,U>      // This inheritance structure is a requirement.
{
...

    using x_type = T;
    using y_type = U;
};
```

The idea is that one can inherit this class and use `X` and `Y` by default, or custom structs derived from `X` and `Y` that provide additional attributes or functions. This all works fine.

The `using ...` typedefs were added so that derived classes (i.e., mixins) "know" what type was used or intended/desired to be used for the base class to facilitate extensibility.

Now, I want to define mixins for `Derived` that can be mixed/matched combined, and so an attempt at that might look like this:

```
template <class D>
struct mixin_x : public D::x_type {
...
};

template <class D>
struct mixin_y : public D::y_type {
...
};

template < template <class, class> class D, class X, class Y,
    class MixinX = mixin_x< D<X,Y> >,
    class MixinY = mixin_y< D<X,Y> > >

using mixin = D<MixinX,MixinY>;
```

The above compiles when the header files are included in a compilation unit. However, there are two issues:

(1) template errors to the effect of 'template argument 1 invalid'

For example, the following code generates the above-referenced error:

```
mixin< Derived<X,Y>, mixin_x< Derived<X,Y> >, mixin_y< Derived<X,Y> > >;
```

Moreover, I can't even omit the 2nd and 3rd arguments to `mixin` above, as the compiler complains that I've supplied 1 template argument when 3 are required. It appears to ignore the default argument, for reasons I do not yet understand.

(2) Unless I am mistaken, the above design does not facilitate wrapping a second mixin on a mixin-wrapped `Derived` class. That is, due to the different number of template parameters, typedef mixin cannot accept `D` to be another mixing designed the same way, and has to be applied directly onto `Derived`.

Any thoughts or pointers (no pun intended!) are appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what are you trying to do, but I see two problems: missing angle brackets and invalid of template template parameters. https://godbolt.org/z/P8re3hPqM

Comment: With respect to angle bracket, that's a typo in the post, not the actual code (fixed). Where is the invalid template template parameter?  Hopefully it's pretty clear from the explanation what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, starting from the second snippet. Also please provide a [mcve] that we can compile and see the same error. Also, why is `Base` mentioned at all?

Comment: @user3814483 `mixin` expects something that can be used with two template parameters as a first argument, you passed something that is not even a template (i.e. you used `Derived<X,Y>` instead of `Derived`). Next, it's not clear why you pass `mixin_x< Derived<X,Y> >` to `mixin` if it's already in the template as `MixinX`)

Comment: I also think that you make things harder than they need to be. If `X` and `Y` are only used in `Derived`, they don't need a separate "mixin systems". If you make `Derived` a CRTP base, you can override `X` and `Y` in the mixins: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YTP4YdWx6

Comment: @HolyBlackCat elegant solution, not sure that it will work here. Based on your post, I think you 100% understand what I'm trying to do. However, the constraint I have, speaking with respect to your example, is that X and Y have to be defined *outside* of DefaultFoo, because it is a requirement that DefaultFoo inherits from another class and passes in X and Y as template arguments to its base class.

Comment: I only understand the general idea of wanting compile-time mixins, but I don't yet understand what's the idea behind the second snippet, or how it achieves that. *"DefaultFoo inherits from another class"* Oh, I see now. Then I would use the outer class as a mere container to hold `X`, `Y`, and the actual class deriving from `Base` and doing stuff: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cn1njYqeG

Comment: @HolyBlackCat PIMPL to the rescue. If you post this solution I'll accept as an answer, most helpful!

Comment: Done. It's not PIMPL though, there's no pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do in the second snippet, but here's my alternative approach to compile-time mixins.

Each mixin takes form of:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Base>
struct MyMixin : Base {};
```

Where `Base` is the next mixin in the chain we must inherit from (or, for the final mixin, the original class we're customizing), and `Derived` is the final class inheriting all the mixins.

First, a mixin combinator:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Base, template <typename, typename> typename ...M>
struct CombineMixins
{
    using type = Base;
};

template <typename Derived, typename Base, template <typename, typename> typename M0, template <typename, typename> typename ...M>
struct CombineMixins<Derived, Base, M0, M...>
{
    using NextBase = typename CombineMixins<Derived, Base, M...>::type;
    using type = M0<Derived, NextBase>;
    static_assert(std::derived_from<type, NextBase>, "Mixins must inherit from their second template parameters.");
};
```

Given a list mixins, the last class in the chain (what we're customizing), and the most-derived class (to pass to mixins), inherits them from one another.

Then the class we're customizing: (I've moved everything to a single class, so you don't need to apply mixins separately to `X` and `Y`)

```
template <typename Derived>
struct DefaultFoo
{
    DefaultFoo() = delete;
    ~DefaultFoo() = delete;

    struct X
    {
        void foo() {std::cout << "I'm X\n";}
    };
    
    struct Y
    {
        void foo() {std::cout << "I'm Y\n";}
    };

    struct Impl : Base<typename Derived::X, typename Derived::Y>
    {
        void run()
        {
            typename Derived::X x;
            x.foo();

            std::cout << "---\n";

            typename Derived::Y y;
            y.foo();
        }
    };
};
```

Since you need to inherit from a base that depends on the mixins, I've created a nested class, and deleted constructors/destructors of the outer one, so it serves as a mere container. If not for the base, you probably could use the outer class directly.

Notice `typename Derived::X` instead of `X` to accept the overrides of those classes from the mixins.

And a small wrapper to apply `CombineMixins` to this class:

```
template <typename Derived, template <typename/*Derived*/, typename/*NextBase*/> typename ...Mixins>
struct BasicFoo : CombineMixins<Derived, DefaultFoo<Derived>, Mixins...>::type {};
```

Here's how you use it:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Base>
struct X_mixin : Base
{
    struct X : Base::X
    {
        void foo()
        {
            Base::X::foo();
            std::cout << "I'm X_mixin::X\n";
        }
    };
};

template <typename Derived, typename Base>
struct Y_mixin : Base
{
    struct Y : Base::Y
    {
        void foo()
        {
            Base::Y::foo();
            std::cout << "I'm Y_mixin::Y\n";
        }
    };
};

struct MyFoo : BasicFoo<MyFoo, X_mixin, Y_mixin> {};

int main()
{
    MyFoo::Impl foo;
    foo.run();
}
```

The final code: <kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACcGqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BeqnpjgIhYZEsMXEAHABstpj2hQxCBEzEBNk%2BfgF2mA6ZTS0ExRHRsQlJCs2t7blctpODocNlo9UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQm%2B25OE8SYrBfYJhoAggdHJ5jnlwQAnsmYAH0CMQmIQFA8nq8XgRMCxkgYYV83L9/sw2KcACKxPAAN0w6FIpxRjFYnwsTCUhJhcIRnwuyL%2BJLYVMZaMwDyJrNJpwAdHyALIQl43LwOU4eMqLfl4VShcEvEwAdisL1OatOXnSRk5/y%2BGNO5KUFxVr0VGONkMh1PhTER9OJbMx2LxBJ1TLJFMwVNhNrt3y5zLdbI5Du5/KSRJ9tKRocDsfZ%2B2wQe5fJ5gsTkJFYolUSlMrl9KxxFx%2BMJhq9p3DhP5qaFppN6o1WuAp3CmFUBHLeuT6JzedlDHBlyLJdd5ertcTIBAxItqvVmtCLeJ3fDhedpdb7c7noh%2Bwb6omtrwyABFKUrQgE3Q06wxZdAKoxFQLHtjMJbY75YehPMZmlA4KKcLCagQpyhAg2JgU%2BL5EpBeDEKcShoAw6CRjStqfMkLSkjCxAKDyf6rHOprmvulrQlGmExgGnzPCyqLclYGbCsCopgV2SpWGaJFWlRfoMox6Iji6dZZmBWJUEwXi0AQABiqCoJayqQo2knSbJCmoBAqzdlg9AwiRjYAH7qTJ8mKTpel1JghnkQq85quJpwABqqeqXHuY2ao4qgeBofw2m6Vx17TmgXhgfS9LnGYZgAJJgBwLCuSYACsbgMH%2BFo8Y55w8fZzyNl5SFsWKACaxWeblja%2Bf5pyBVZIUEDeKCbJFlzRX%2BCVJacFXpZlsXZeauVKmRJrFc5cU0qcIAGru/pCZ8In4tOLkMe6Tr3itIAVSxhUeSp1XqrVaHEF4DA6cVRWHft3nefGm2jqtpyqEZd3eaoPINcRBVXe9oWtRFSKdbFAC04NpRlWW/Udd0PctLVlacPxve96o/F9lk/Qed2jZV%2BXjQTFHPAA9CTpyFW4ABKAAqyinFEnqEZRGECfDG6uta0ZvotJMAFQI3zJPrWy/OfjuShCyGtG8gK%2BaDmJpUcRSJ5aTN4ovrmYQAQWw4c4SZmaYp65begP6VvLBF8g804rp5RMOaT5Pg6DxNc9RPMbQjItMfNjysWdYouQCLDy%2Br34KjdjbOS54eeqt%2BM495J31Vjf1qlVt1o3NSirdO32o9nAPhe1bgg/FiXJcHocDgn/XQ0n13DVneO/Q7ULPO7bMy97PYekae3OWVIdh7NEf1hNSu9XHuc7Yn6enCnBew3ljfveW05lfnacFdnh7NWFbXA5cMUVz1w816Em%2BQwNZiF03%2BNjcpT%2BO85/I/GrY8q8gWn0u/WmEmrvLQkF95Ycnti/DuoQwIsFBBdYikck7/0UtOKa8JU5KV3uqQKPIzrwN4maDg6xaCcFSrwPwHAtCkFQJwMulhrBIU2NsOkZh9g8FIAQTQRD1gAGsQCSHiDyWKqVFQaESPECo8QuCKgqPsfQnBJDkK4dQzgvAFAgCSJwyhRDSBwFgDARArU4R0FiOQSgaBjH0DiMcQwwAuBVA0EkLAOITyYAAGp4EwAAdwAPKok4OwmgslYjqIgFEZRWsWg/ACbwSJxAfg%2BKiNoHoWj2EWLYIIHxDBaDRO0aQLAUQvDADcGIWg6juC8CwLAow4g8n4FuL0PE5SqHth6BFXYVDoF1GUbQPAUQQTxI8FgGJHDiwsBiesKgBhgAKA8d4vxjARn8EECIMQ7ApAyEEIoFQ6g8m6ACAYIwKBrDWH0H09RkB1ioGSA0cpoNrwXAxKYehlgzAaFOKDAA6qUj5nztwgg%2Bf8dAhhHDIFBrEZ8%2BFflYGSA0zC6BeCoDxMQYsWALk6RSIYCIpIQBuEOcAWo9RMguFQtMPwsxgiLFKOUPIaQMgCDJbSgomQhjUtGLMbovQBD9CmJ4DoehOUNB5QsEoIw4gcvmIyiVAxWViokOsBQTCdjyvkRwMhpAKFUJoXi2xHCuHrAgEgCxyQTFkAoBAY1pqQB2LYfkzALidhzN8f4ipfA6B4VCeEvJcTcnsJ9Yk5JDgRnpMYAQLJOTlEFKKSU2gZSRlVNsbUqh9SUklmabwVpyB2nKK6SQvJvT%2BlRKGbsdhwI8DjIqZM6ZszPHOsWa65ZwhRDiA2Y27ZahlG6FmPi45LybAFvRVcm5mQ7kPP2E8k5rz3lfJ%2BV8/5TBAX4hBSecFKKSBAS%2BTCuFMIEXUORaizAg7MUlBxQAcTcG4QlqbnAQFcFKwIqFZXLHFSkOlDR735HpQwJ9NKOU2S5Y0SVfKZhXoA8Kn97K5gDHvUeVoEHxUKqVes4hpClF5Joeey9WitCrHWJBJgd5KAoY4Io0g4zJBVB5JIDQrCBGSGqBoAR8Q5GasRao2wGi9XaINQYw1IA2rJAimYi1L4TVWPCDijgqhqigyqJIU4NjtRcFSjyDQqmM34CIKivQjbVktrkW2pQHa9n%2BGPditgtD8WnAExFXgXiQTJH1aq9VrGVEcB1dqGzBBeDYZ0XxrzwnLXick9Jqosn5PAGQMgU4XAzBCI04QEg/kdOyD0%2Bsgzsh227KoV2szEmLMcEw9ZiKgnvOkHs0wRz3HnNoa1ZwIrXmfP6rw3cQjGK82kfGalfYPJUrxEVFUVKGhUpcH2PEIbGhFQauUTQjgajOO%2Bdw6QPhQ2eSKkVJIMw4iNBcA0BUMw0jVX7Fq2xubXGcPEbMCdtzTXuPrGRekZwkggA%3D)</kbd>